# PHP - Foreach does echo the values but do not push it to array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array $x that looks somehting like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 280123736
        [BuyItNowPrice] => 600
        [SellerId] => 3635925
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 280195277
        [SellerId] => 4269145
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 280195291
        [SellerId] => 4269145
     )

)
```

Now, I want to push all values with key "Id" to a new array but I can't get it to work. I have a function that recursively go through the array like so:

```
$ids = array();
function get_ids($arr) {
    if ($arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                get_ids($value);
            } else {
                if ($key == "Id") {
                    //None of these seem to work
                    //Tried them both separately of course
                    $ids[] = $value;
                    array_push($ids, $value);

                    //But printing out the values does work
                    echo "[". $key ."]: " . $value . "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I call the function like so:

```
echo "--Call get_ids() \n";
get_ids($x);

echo "--Print $ids \n";
print_r($ids);

echo "--Print $ids length \n";
count($ids);
```

The output of this is:

```
--Call get_ids()
[Id]: 280123736
[Id]: 280195277
[Id]: 280195291

--Print $ids
Array
(
)

--Print $ids length 
(No output here..)
```

I console.log the result with javascript calling the php script through AJAX if that is something that matters, like so:

```
$.ajax ({
        url: "script.php",
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
});
```

However I need to extract the "Ids" in the php script. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just: `$ids = array_column($x, 'Id');`

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Thank you! Where do I mark your answer as solved?

Comment: It's probably a duplicate but I answered just in case.

Comment: Just curious. Why doesn't my code work?

Comment: I don't know, it's overly complicated but I'll add a foreach so that you get the idea that it is very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this to get all `Id`s into an array:

```
$ids = array_column($x, 'Id');
```

As for the `foreach` approach, it is much simpler as well:

```
foreach($x as $value) {
    if(isset($value['Id'])) {
        $ids[] = $value['Id'];
    }           
}
```